# Subtract 1 from unique concatenated variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've wrote a script that gives the user the option to add more than one image to a form. If the user chooses to add more than one image, they click the 'Add another image' button, and another file field is added.

When the new file field is added, the id given to that field is unique. The first field is statically set to "1". If the user clicks 'Add another image', the second field is given the id of "2", then another would be "3" etc etc. This has been working successfully.

**Note:**

I'm not giving them the option to remove the first file field at all.

**The issue:**

Due to the fact that I want to check that each file field has actually got a file ready for upload, I've decided to add a 'Remove this image' next to each field when the 'Add another image' button is selected.

Ideally, when the user clicks the 'Remove this image' button, the id of the fields after that field are all changed by -1.

**EG:** The user has inserted five additional file fields using the 'Add another image' button, and they have clicked on the 'Remove this image' button next to the file field with the id of '3', meaning that '4', '5' and '6' should become '3', '4' and '5'.

**Edit:**
**Current functionality:**

The id's are being subtracted accordingly, however when a new field is added, it is continuing from the previous count. **EG:** If file fields '5' and '6' are removed, then another one is added, it is given the id of '7'.

If any of you can help me with this dilemma it'd be much appreciated. It's frying my head a little.

Thanks in advance, Rich

**Here are my efforts thus far:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var count = 2;
$('#addImage').click(function(){
var countNew = count++;
$('#newsFormContainer #addImage').before( $('<div id="added"><br /><label for="' + countNew + '">Image ' + countNew + '</label class="strong" ><br /><input type="file" class="file" name="' + countNew + '" id="' + countNew + '" accept=".png"></div>'));
$('#newsFormContainer #addImage').before( $('<button id="' +  countNew + '" class="file" onclick="return false;">Remove this image</button>'));


$('button.file').click(function(){
var grabClass = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=file]');

console.log(grabClass)

$(grabClass).attr('id', function(index){
     return index + 1;
});
$(this).prev('#added').remove();
$(this).remove();
});

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[file^=file]').length;
document.getElementById('cnt').value = inputs;

});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try Running this Code**; may be this solves your problem

```js
$('#add-item').on('click', function() {
  var indexOfLastItem = parseInt($('ul>li:last').attr('data-index'));
  if(!indexOfLastItem){
    indexOfLastItem = 0;
    }
  indexOfLastItem += 1;
  $('ul').append('<li data-index="' + indexOfLastItem + '">Item ' + indexOfLastItem + '<button>Remove Image</button></li>')
});


/**
 * Dynamically assigning event handler
 *  Other wise it will not work for 'Remove' buttons added in runtime
 *
 */
$(document).on('click', 'li> button', function() {
  var indexOfLi = $(this).parent().attr('data-index');
  var $currentLi = $(this).parents('li');
  var $itemsAfterCurrent = $currentLi.nextAll();
  console.log($itemsAfterCurrent);

  rearrangeItems($itemsAfterCurrent);

  $currentLi.hide('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })

})

function rearrangeItems($itemsAfterCurrent) {
  $itemsAfterCurrent.each(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    index = parseInt(index) - 1;
    console.log(index);
    $(this).attr('data-index', index);
    $(this).html('Item ' + index + '<button>Remove Image</button>');
  });
}
```

```css
li{
  margin: 5px;
  }
li>button{
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-index="1">Item 1 <button>Remove Image</button></li>
  <li data-index="2">Item 2<button>Remove Image</button></li>
  <li data-index="3">Item 3<button>Remove Image</button></li>
  <li data-index="4">Item 4<button>Remove Image</button></li>
  <li data-index="5">Item 5<button>Remove Image</button></li>
  <li data-index="6">Item 6<button>Remove Image</button></li>
</ul>  
<button id="add-item">Add Image</button>
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: This worked a treat. Added the file inputs into the li's and concat'd the values in accordingly. Much appreciated man.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop that checks the id of the deleted picture and the for all pictures with an id greater then the picture being deleted subtract 1 from the value of their id.